# Extending Laravel 5.2 SessionGuard

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to extend the Laravel stock authentication to use an OAuth server for user retrieval and authentication while taking advantage of the existing functionality. I already managed to extend the `EloquentUserProvider` to partially overwrite/extend the implementations of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` contract. The current implementation looks like this:

```
class EloquentOauthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return HcOAuthProvider;
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::provider('oauth',function($app){
            $model = $app['config']['auth.providers.oauth.model'];
            $repository = new OauthUserRepository();
            return new EloquentOauthUserProvider($app['hash'], $model, $repository);
        });
    }

}
```

In the `auth.php` config I changed the descriptors like this:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'oauth',
    ],
]

'providers' => [
    'oauth' => [
        'driver' => 'oauth',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
]
```

This is working so far, I can overwrite methods to add my logic. But I realized that I also need to overwrite some methods of the `SessionGuard` class (`login` and `logout` to be specific) since I want to save and retrieve OAuth specific tokens using the Laravel session implementation. There are a couple of suggestions around but they are either not working (Maybe they worked before Laravel 5.2) or would require to overwrite the `Authmanager` which looks like overkill.

So my question is: What I have to do in Laravel 5.2 to overwrite the SessionGuard?

Answer (score 11):

Recently I've had the same problem, so maybe the solution is something like this.

```
<?php
namespace App\CoreExtensions;
use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class SessionGuardExtended extends SessionGuard
{
    /**
     * Log a user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false)
    {
        $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());
        if ($remember) {
            $this->refreshRememberToken($user);
            $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
        }
        $this->fireLoginEvent($user, $remember);
        $this->setUser($user);
    }
}
```

In AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Auth::extend(
        'sessionExtended',
        function ($app) {
            $provider = new EloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], config('auth.providers.users.model'));
            return new SessionGuardExtended('sessionExtended', $provider, app()->make('session.store'), request());
        }
    );
}
```

In Config/auth.php driver should be renamed

```
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'sessionExtended',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: Helpful answer. For those looking at this, I just wanted to add a reference back to the docs Authentication [Adding Custom Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#adding-custom-guards). The answer above follows the same pattern given there, just that in the auth.config it's "replace built in guard" rather than "add new guard"

Answer (score 1):

Extend guard:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;

class MySessionGuard extends SessionGuard {
    // ...
}
```

Update configs

```php
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'my-session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

Bind new guard in AuthServiceProvider.php:

```php
public function boot()
    {
        Auth::extend(
            'my-session',
            function ($app, $name, array $config) {
                /* Copy functionality form Auth::createSessionDriver */
                $guard = new MySessionGuard($name, Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null), $this->app['session.store']);
                if (method_exists($guard, 'setCookieJar')) {
                    $guard->setCookieJar($this->app['cookie']);
                }
                if (method_exists($guard, 'setDispatcher')) {
                    $guard->setDispatcher($this->app['events']);
                }
                if (method_exists($guard, 'setRequest')) {
                    $guard->setRequest($this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest'));
                }

                return $guard;
            }
        );

       // ...
    }
```