# Laravel authentication with remember me error

Tags: laravel, authentication, cookies, remember-me

I use `auth()->attempt()` with remember me parameters.

```php
if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $rememberMe)) {
```

When remember me is false, I can login normally,
but when remember me is true, I got an error.

```
RuntimeException
Cookie jar has not been set.
```

I tried to set .env
from `SESSION_DRIVER=file`
to  `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie`

but still didn't work.

I'm using Laravel 7.24 and PHP 7.4.11

Comment: did you clear config & cache after changing your .env?

Comment: Thanks, tried config:clear, cache:clear but still got the same error.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Is the issue still there? Struggling with the same bug right now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using a custom Auth Guard that extended the built in SessionGuard. I had to set the cookie jar myself with

```
$this->setCookieJar(app('cookie'));
```

YMMV.

Comment: Yes need manually set jar - even if extend class. Example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69179026/5533775)

Comment: where did you set the cookie jar ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in my case when I used a custom guard. Calling setCookieJar, setDispatcher and setRequest on my guard solved the problem.
Look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/wayanjimmy/afa85e211e2cdd6bacf5daa849bac749)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem for myself by putting `'driver' => 'session'` under `guards` array in `config/auth.php`. But I was using different guard for admin panel authentication, so it might just be that you have this misconfigured as well.